Why is my swift alamofire sending get instead of post, also happened when i did not use the module?
import SwiftUI
import Alamofire

struct TestView: View {
    
    // Function to send the POST request using Alamofire
    func sendPostRequest() {
        // URL and data
        let url = ""
        
        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "UserName": "",
            "Password": "",
            "__RequestVerificationToken": "",
            "submitbut": "Submit"
        ]
        
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Host": "",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.6778.86 Safari/537.36",
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
            "Referer": "",
            "Cookie": "__RequestVerificationToken=_"
        ]
        
        // Making the POST request with Alamofire
        AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .validate()
            .response { response in
                if let response = response.response {
                    print("Response Status Code: \(response.statusCode)")
                }
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    if let str = String(data: data ?? Data(), encoding: .utf8) {
                        print("Response: \(str)")
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }

    }    

i removed my requesttoken, website and user details.. when server response printed, always appear as get rrequest response
i have ensured all my cookies are correct, but for some reason im still getting get request reply... have tried many ways, including adding a slash at the end of the url but to no avail.
when i ran this same command in curl bash, i got the correct response to the post request but for some reason on swift when i run this, i keep on getting the get response back
when i debug w alamofirelog, i get this
Request Method: POST
but response is still what i get from a GET request

Your question is quite unclear. You didn't explain why you need a Cookie header, then you did not show the actual request and the actual response (utilising a tool). Then, if you expect a different response from your actual request, it's also the responsibility of the server, which you might have to investigate, too.  Also, you could have used a URLSession in replacement of Alamofire to see what happens then. As it stands now, you sent a request (which, technically, does not look wrong to me) and got a response,  which you expect to be different.

"when i ran this same command in curl bash, i got the correct response to the post request" Did you try with the cURL command debug that can be retrived from Alamofire and test that one?

Do it by adding AF.request(url, ...).cURLDescription { print("curlCommand1: \($0)") }.validate().response { ... }
